# Rails4: Cannot send email from lib/module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have this weird thing going on in my rails4 app:

I created `event.rb` in the `lib` folder.

In there, I call a mailer:

```
def whatever
  puts 'here'
  UserMailer.welcome(user)
  puts 'there'
end
```

which is calling

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.mailer, subject: 'Welcome to my app').deliver
  end
end
```

The weird thing is that the method `welcome` is never called, while `whatever` is called, without raising any error (the logs are there).

But if I call `UserMailer.welcome(User.first)` in the console, it is sent.

What am I doing wrong? Is it that it is not possible to send an email from a module? I should move this code to a model? That would be weird.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add `puts "test"` inside the mailer action, and look if it is printing there.. How are you confirming if the email action is not getting called from `lib` ?

Comment: You can most certainly call mailers from modules, as @ArupRakshit already pointed out the error is most likely in your methodology. You may want to use `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` so that rails will simply spool emails into `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` which is just an array for testing your method. Better yet is to write a test or spec for your module. http://blog.lucascaton.com.br/index.php/2010/10/25/how-to-test-mailers-in-rails-3-with-rspec/

Comment: it might be the delivery method in your current Rails environment. Putting a `puts` in your code or a log statement should help.  You could also put a `puts` statement before the definition of welcome, so you see when the class is loaded

Comment: You could try a `require_relative` at the top of your `event.rb` file. You would need to add this `require_relative ../app/mailers/user_mailer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO mailer should look like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.mailer, subject: 'Welcome to my app') #.deliver removed
  end
end
```

and should be invoked with this manner:

```
def whatever
  puts 'here'
  UserMailer.welcome(user).deliver_now # and added here
  puts 'there'
end
```

Comment: I have `.deliver` in the mailer because I'm using [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) which in Rails3, forces me to have such behavior. Since I upgraded to Rails4, this might not be necessary anymore so I may change this.

Comment: Not a 100% sure what was going on, but I listed all my mailers and did the following: 1. Removed the `.deliver` in the mailer 2. Called the mailer either with `UserMailer.welcome(user).deliver_now` or with `UserMailer.delay.welcome(user)`. DelayedJob's doc is not very clear, I'll report there about it. Also I'm not clear why the method is `.deliver` *in* the mailer and `.deliver_now` *outside* the mailer as `mail()` is what should be returned from the mailer method, shouldn't it? Anyways, it works :)

Comment: I'm currently working with rails 4.2 where `deliver` method is deprecated and replaced by `deliver_now` or `deliver_later`. I tried your code and either I've used `.deliver` in the mailer or not, and when `User.welcome` was invoked always only `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` object has been created. Maybe it is a rails 4 specific  behaviour...